# How to split IPv6 range into specific sizes?

Tags: ip-address, ipv6, ipv4

I'm trying to map an IPv4 CIDR range onto its IPv6 equivalent, for use in an AWS WAF Classic rule.

AWS WAF Classic only allows IPv6 address ranges: `/24`, `/32`, `/48`, `/56`, `/64`, and `/128`.

Given the IP range `147.161.128.0/17` (which covers `147.161.128.0` -> `147.161.255.255`), any online conversion tool will generate the corresponding IPv6 range:
`::ffff:147.161.128.0/113`

However, since that's a `/113` block, AWS WAF won't accept it.

How can I generate a list of IPv6 ranges that cover the same range as the original IPv4 range `147.161.128.0/17` but comprise only `/24`, `/32`, `/48`, `/56`, `/64`, and `/128` blocks?

Comment: What do you mean by "generate"? Is there any code involved?

Comment: The entire IPv4 range fits inside a `/96`. Also, addressing in the IPv4-Mapped IPv6 range (`::ffff:0.0.0.0/96`) cannot be used as addresses on packets. Those are not real IPv6 addresses. That range is reserved to allow IPv4 addresses to be displayed in the IPv6 format to be used in a common IPv4/IPv6 data store. For your network, you almost always use `/64`. The shorter prefixes are to delegate multiple IPv6 networks, and `/127` is for point-to-point links, and `/128` is for loopbacks. IPv6 is simpler than IPv4 in that regard.

Comment: Remember that IPv4 and IPv6 are completely separate, incompatible protocols. The addressing is incompatible, and you cannot really do what you suggest, nor would it be a good idea. Given a `/32` prefix, you get as many standard `/64` networks as there are possible Individual IPv4 addresses. IPv6 is designed to waste addresses while IPv4 needs address conservation. Do not try to apply IPv4-thinking to IPv6.

Comment: OK, thank you. It's clear that I know even less about this than I thought I did. So to summarize: even though I can express any _single_ IPv4 address in IPv6 notation there's **no way** to express my original 147.161.128.0/17 range as an IPv6 range (or list of ranges) using the range prefixes / blocks / bits after the slash that AWS WAF permits?

Comment: That is something you really do not want to do. Imagine that you want to do that with Novell IPX or AppleTalk. IPv6 is also another different incompatible protocol. and it does not relate to IPv4 in that way.

Comment: In fact, IPv6 addressing is similar to IPX addressing. IPX has a 32-bit network and 48-bit host. IPv6 (in most cases) will have a 64-bit network and 64-bit host. When IPv6 was being designed, the IPX addressing model was one of those floated for it.